# does putting CultureInfo.InvariantCulture mean always same behavior?

Tags: c#

I made a C# app that basically parses some html, including numbers. On my computer everything worked perfectly well so I published it and one user told me that it doesn't work, so he sent me a log and there was that 2.5 cannot be parsed into double. What? So I used Google and found out that putting CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to parsing may help. I put into every .ToString() .Parse() etc. It works now but before I publish it I need to know whether it will work on every single computer exactly as on mine. If it doesn't, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Yes passing a `CultureInfo` into `ToString()` and `Parse()` type methods will ensure that that string format is consistent rather than based on the culture of the thread.

Comment: But now are your numbers specified in your locale setting correctly converted to a double? I.E. What is the result when you get a "2,5"? Could you show how do you convert that string to a double?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to [MSDN: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Unlike culture-sensitive data, which is subject to change by user customization or by updates to the .NET Framework or the operating system, invariant culture data is stable over time and across installed cultures and cannot be customized by users. This makes the invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations that persist formatted data, or sorting and ordering operations that require that data be displayed in a fixed order regardless of culture.